# Disk path changes from boot to boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, mount

I have a disk

sudo lshw -C disk

```
 *-disk
   description: ATA Disk
   product: Corsair CSSD-F12
   physical id: 0.0.0
   bus info: scsi@7:0.0.0
   logical name: /dev/sde
   version: 2.0
   serial: 10516505330003430015
   size: 111GiB (120GB)
   capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
   configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=21ec30ba-0aab-4ce9-be03-8f6f4de1afa1 sectorsize=512
```

I've mounted it yesterday:
cat /etc/fstab

```
/dev/sdg1 /home/ssa/mnt/corsair ext4 defaults 0 0
```

Yesterday it had path **/dev/sdg1** now it's **/dev/sde** and mount is not working.
Why name is changed after reboot?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Such device names are not *persistent*, `udev` makes no guarantees that they will be the same. The [Arch Wiki says](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Udev#Setting_static_device_names):

> Because udev loads all modules asynchronously, they are initialized in a different order. This can result in devices randomly switching names. A udev rule can be added to use static device names.

You should use labels or UUIDs instead.

First, get the UUID:

```
sudo blkid -o export /path/to/device | grep UUID
```

Then use:

```
UUID=... /path/to/mount/point type ...
```

For example:

```
$ sudo blkid -o export /dev/sda3 | grep UUID
UUID=d3504dc2-8f01-48f1-be05-d265110e2e73
```

And the corresponding entry would be:

```
UUID=d3504dc2-8f01-48f1-be05-d265110e2e73 /   ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```